# Unit testing: mock static class used in my ViewModel

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am using a static class (`MyStaticClass`) inside a ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    //whatever...

    public void FooMethod()
    {
        MyProperty = MyStaticClass.PropertyOne;
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I mock `MyStaticClass` in the `MyViewModel` unit tests?

Comment: wrap MyStaticClass into a non-static class which implements some interface and you're done.

Comment: Gracias Roberto ;-) I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely agree that you should avoid using static classes if you wish to unit test however if you have no choice about the static class then controlling it's behaviour for the sake of unit tests can be done (although strictly speaking this is not mocking!)

For example the DateTime class contains the very useful DateTime.Now static method but it is a total pain when unit testing because "now" is always changing. To get round this I created a static class that wraps it;

```
public static class SystemTime
{
    private static DateTime _date;

    public static DateTime Now => _date != DateTime.MinValue ? _date : DateTime.Now;

    public static DateTime Today => _date == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Today : _date.Date;

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void Set(DateTime date)
    {
        _date = date;
    }

    public static void Reset()
    {
        _date = DateTime.MinValue;
    }
}
```

This is an example of a static class that can be manipulated for unit tests. In your test class set-up method you can "Set" SystemTime so that it will always return the value you want, making testing code that calls the current time testable. The important part for your own static class is being able to set up the static class in a "test" state so that in a unit test it behaves in one way but in release code it behaves differently.

To do this you'll have to add properties or methods that can be set to change the functionality of your code. There is a problem though, it's static so once it is set it stays set. To get round this you absolutely must remember to revert the class back to it's "live" state, I would put this code in the tear-down method of your test class so that you can't forget to reset it.  The other problem is that these methods and properties you introduce could potentially be called by non-test code. To avoid this you can set the "DEBUG" attribute  or wrap the test-only methods/properties in #if DEBUG blocks. This doesn't stop you from accidentally setting the properties during development but it will break the release build and flag the issue. Use this approach with care!

EDIT:

If I had a static class that I could not make non-static and the class was more than the trivial example above I would create an interface then create a wrapper for the static class that implements this interface and a mock class that also implements this interface. I would pass in the class either in the constructor (preferred by me) or set it as a property. In the tests pass in the mock version, but in your real implementation pass in your wrapped version.

Comment: Hello. What about if I wrap this class in a service which implements a interface, and inject it in the constructor using IoC? Would it be better?

Comment: Yes that's a great technique to use, I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: how can I mock MyStaticClass in the MyViewModel unit tests?

The answer to your question is more than simple:

**You can't**.

Once you have gotten rid of the static crap from your code, you might put unit testing back to the table. You might even think about unit testing the different classes of your application in isolation from their concrete dependencies. So before unit testing, spend a little bit more time on designing. Yes, of course, you can spend $$$s on some advanced *unit testing frameworks* that will do some voodoo magic at runtime like replacing your assemblies with some weaved code, injecting stuff, etc..., but honestly, spending some time on designing will be a more profitable approach at the long run.

But until you have spent some time into thinking and designing your code appropriately here's a cheap trick you could employ to improve your code coverage:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    internal static Func<string> MyPropertyInjector = () => MyStaticClass.PropertyOne;

    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    //whatever...

    public void FooMethod()
    {
        this.MyProperty = MyPropertyInjector();
    }
}
```

and then in your [`unit test the friendly assembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// arrange
MyViewModel.MyPropertyInjector = () => "some expected value";

// act
var sut = new MyViewModel();
sut.FooMethod();

// assert
Assert.AreEqual("some expected value", sut.MyProperty);
```

But as I said earlier, that's just a trick into improving your code coverage, but you should not be fooled into thinking that this trick is improving your code quality. For this you might need to spend some more time thinking and designing.

Comment: like you say, I think the bigger issue here is design and that a viewmodel has such complex logic in it that it depends on other classes. it should just be a dumb container of pre-calculated values from the domain model

Comment: Thank you for your words, but...shouldn't be better to wrap this class in a service which implements a interface, and inject it in the constructor using IoC?

Comment: This isolated service would be easily mocked and tested as well.

Comment: BTW I think we should be a bit friendlier with our replys in this community. It is true that we must keep our "evangelist" speech, but sometimes there are several cases where, at the practise, you need to use some patterns that sometimes you don't like, I imagine that even you have done it. Anyway, thanks a lot for your support :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock static classes.  It is recommended to avoid static classes except in the creation of deterministic functions. e.g. you pass this value, you always get this value back - think helper functions and the like.

Static classes that manipulate data or rely on some sort of state are extremely difficult to test.  If nothing else, you can create a wrapper for your static class which will help alleviate some of this problem, but you'll still probably run into issues testing the wrapper class.

Comment: Thanks @Kritner, I think the best solution is to wrap this static class in a external service and inject it in my ViewModel constructor using IoC. Thanks.